# Cannot load Q# language extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, quantum-computing, q#

I installed the quantum development kit from the microsoft site:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/development-kit

But when I try to open one of the projects or create a Q# I get the message:

> There was an error activating the remote language server, Q# Language Extension. For more details, please run devenv /log and examine ....\ActivityLog.xml file.

I ran it and found:

> ERROR
>       System.SystemException: The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed. at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed) at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean& someFailed) at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess) at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType) at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.ModifyAccess(AccessControlModification modification, AccessRule rule, Boolean& modified) at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule(AccessRule rule) at System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(PipeAccessRule rule) at Microsoft.Quantum.QsLanguageExtensionVS.QsLanguageClient.d__24.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.RemoteLanguageServiceBroker.RemoteLanguageClientInstance.d__49.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.d__12.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.RemoteLanguageServiceBroker.RemoteLanguageClientInstance.d__47.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
>
> Q# Language Extension

So I have no intellisense and the *.qs files are not as Q# recognized.

**Visual Studio 2017 15.9**

**Windows 10 1809**

Any idea about this?

Comment: What language is your Windows installation in? We've never seen this error before, but we have a possible theory.

Comment: @AlanGeller I have 3 environments:
Working: Windows 10 English. VS 2017 15.9 English -
Not Working: 
Windows 10 German base but with English Language pack. VS 2017 15.9 English. 
Windows 10 Spanish. VS 2017 15.9 English .

So the two machines were it is not working have a SO base in non english language.

Comment: Ah -- that's consistent with our theory. I'll post here when we're able to publish a potential fix. Sorry about this!

Comment: @AlanGeller Thanks!. In the meantime I can continue using VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have posted a new version of the [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quantum.DevKit) (0.3.1811.1501) which we believe should fix the problem. Do you mind [updating the extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-update-a-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2017) and giving it a try?

Comment: Thanks, I will try as soon as possible, I think in two days when I have access to all the environment and will let you know

Comment: I can confirm the new version fixed this problem. I get intellisense, tooltips and file icons. Thanks for the quick update.